# Updating UI components from an async callback (dispatch_queue)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, queue

how can i update GUI elements with values from a queue?
if i use async queue construct, textlable don't get updated.
Here is a code example i use:

```
- (IBAction)dbSizeButton:(id)sender {
    dispatch_queue_t getDbSize = dispatch_queue_create("getDbSize", NULL);
    dispatch_async(getDbSize, ^(void)
    {
        [_dbsizeLable setText:[dbmanager getDbSize]]; 
    });

   dispatch_release(getDbSize);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @MarkGranoff said, all UI needs to be handled on the main thread. You could do it with performSelectorOnMainThread, but with GCD it would be something like this:

```
- (IBAction)dbSizeButton:(id)sender {

    dispatch_queue_t getDbSize = dispatch_queue_create("getDbSize", NULL);
    dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(getDbSize, ^(void)
    {
        dispatch_async(main, ^{ 
            [_dbsizeLable setText:[dbmanager getDbSize]];
        });
    });

    // release
}
```

Comment: Except you'd probably want the -getDbSize occurring on the private queue, not the main queue...

Comment: @Catfish_Man: But isn't getDbSize the private queue?

Comment: It's not happening on the getDbSize queue. It's happening in a dispatch_async'd block running on the main queue. You need it inside the first dispatch_async, but outside the second.

Answer (score 2):

Any UI update must be performed on the main thread. So your code would need to modified to use the main dispatch queue, not a queue of your own creation. Or, any of the `performSelectorOnMainThread` methods would work as well. (But GCD is the way to go, these days!)